# How to find similar Sentences using FastText ( Sentences with Out of Vocabulary words)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim, fasttext

I am trying to create an NLP model which can find similar sentences. For example, It should be able to say that "Software Engineer", "Software Developer", "Software Dev", "Soft Engineer" are similar sentences.

I have a dataset with a list of roles such as Cheif Executives, Software Engineer and the variation of these terms will be unknown ( out of vocabulary).

I am trying to use fastText with Gensim but struggling.
Does anyone have suggested readings/ tutorials that might help me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange forum as it is not directly related to programming issue. Please move the question there.

Comment: I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mere list-of-roles may not be enough data for FastText (and similar word2vec-like algorithms), which need to see words (or tokens) **in natural ussage contexts**, alongside other related words, to gradually nudge them into interesing relative-similarity alignments.

Do you just have the titles, or other descriptions of the roles?

To the extent that the titles are composed of individual words, which in their title-context mostly mean the same as in normal contexts, and they are very short (2-3 words each), one potential approach is to try the "word mover's distance" (WMD) metric.

You'd want good word-vectors trained from elsewhere with good contexts and compatible word senses, so that the vectors for `'software'`, '`engineer'`, etc individually are all reasonably good. Then you could use the `.wmdistance()` method in Gensim's word-vector classes to calculate a measure of how much, across all of a texts words, one run-of-words differs from another run-of-words.

**Update**: Note that for the values from WMD (and those from cosine-similarity), you generally *shouldn't* obsess over their absolute values, only how they affect relative rankings. That is, no matter what raw value `wmd(['software', 'engineer'], ['electric', 'engineer'])` returns, be it `0.01` or `100`, the important measure is how that number compares to other pairwise comparisons, like say `wmd(['software', 'engineer'], ['software', 'developer'])`.

Comment: I have titles and descriptions. However, the title is not used in the description. 

I attempted the word movers metric on the word2vec-google-news-300 dataset and it seems like it is not very accurate. It says the titles like 'software engineer' and 'electric engineer' are very close whereas they are not. 

Do you have any suggestions on where I can get good word-vectors trained from elsewhere with compatible word senses?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In the world of all 2-word utterances `software engineer` & `electric engineer` are quite close! But also, see the *update* I added to the answer about the proper interpretation of WMD or cosine-similarity values. Yes, also, for WMD like other word-vector projects, you really want to use word-vectors relevant to your domain. (The `GoogleNews` vectors are from news articles, and are getting a bit old at 8+ years, so despite the 3M words, may not have the right new lingo, abbreviations, & word-senses as modern proejcts in other domains needs.) …

Comment: If you have enough data, training your own word-vectors from text exact texts you're analyzing is often best. You could try running the titles & descriptions together for a common word-model. You could try including the titles as *both* their multiple-token versions (`['senior', 'software', 'engineer']`) and an artificial compound token (`['senior_software_engineer']`) - so your model gets ideas of both the individual words & the full-title, to the extent it repeats.

Comment: With a fixed set of titles (in raw data or after cleaniup), you could consider `fasttext` `-supervised` mode, to predict the full-title from text descriptions. (Note this mode isn't implemented in Gensim.) You could try applying Gensim's `Doc2Vec`, with the titles, or title words as the doc-tags. Depending on your intended usage of the similarity-scores, other text-classification or text-clustering or text-ranking algorithms could be considered. For some uses, even just simple shared-substring/edit-distance measure might help associate typos/nonstandard wordings to standard titles.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I will attempt these techniques and update!